# When creating a single pointer array for representing a 2D array, what is the size of the pointer array? Is it row or column of the 2D array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

So, this code was given by my teacher and it works fine, but I am confused as to why it is `int (*x1)[3];` and not `int (*x1)[2];` as `y` has 2 rows only. I think that each element of this array `x1` will store the address to the row of `y` so only two such elements are required and not 3. Kindly help me. Thank you

```
int main(){
int (*x1)[3];
int y[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
x1 = y;
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
    printf("\n The X1 is %d and Y is %d",*(*(x1+i)+j), y[i][j]);
return 0;
}
```

I tried running this code and it is working fine. I don't understand how it is working though. Like what is going on internally? How is the memory being allocated?

Comment: Note that `x1` is a single pointer and assigning `x1 = y;` only sets that pointer. No data is copied. This variable's size is the size of a pointer. It only points to an object with rows of the same length (3). For a 2-D array, C doesn't really care how many rows there are (except when allocating the memory). It's up to the programmer not to exceed them.

Comment: ... *"each element of this array `x1` will store the address to the row of `y`"*. The pointer `x1` doesn't have any elements; it only points to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

```c
int y[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Every element in `y` is an `int[3]` and `y` has 2 such elements. This declares a pointer to one such element:

```c
int (*x1)[3];
```

And in this, `y` decays into a pointer to the first element which is why the assignment works:

```
x1 = y;
```

---

Suggestion for making it a little easier to read:

```c
x1 = y;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i, ++x1) // step x1 here
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        printf("\n The X1 is %d and Y is %d", (*x1)[j], y[i][j]);
// and dereferencing it becomes nicer here    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `*(*(x1+i)+j)` -> `x1[i][j]` ?

Comment: @tstanisl That works too if we skip stepping the `int[3]` pointer in the outer loop. I thought it would prove more useful to step the pointer to show what it is since OP thought it should be an `int[2]` pointer.

Comment: OP however never reacted to the answer in any way so I'm not sure if I made anything clearer :-/